# Diagonal movement of a sprite

Tags: java, keylistener

How can I implement diagonal movement to a sprite? I created a movable sprite (a rectangle), which moves in four directions.

To animate the rectangle, a timer object and action performed method was used. I implemented the following code in keyPressed and keyReleased method to move it in four directions.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0){
    int c=arg0.getKeyCode();
    if(c==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        velx=-4;
        vely=0;
    }
    else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        velx=4;
        vely=0;
    }
    else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        velx=0;
        vely=-4;
    }
    else if(c==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        velx=0;
        vely=4;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0){
    velx=0;
    vely=0;
}
```

Comment: So whats your question? How to detect if two key are being pressed at once?

Comment: I'd use boolean flags, keep a indication of what's been pressed and what hasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code based on your last comments:

```
// Set of currently pressed keys
private final Set<Integer> pressed = new TreeSet<Integer>();

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    int c = arg0.getKeyCode();
    pressed.add(c);
    if (pressed.size() > 1) {
        Integer[] array = pressed.toArray(new Integer[] {});
        if (array[0] == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && array[1] == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            velx = -4;
            vely = -4;
        } else if (array[0] == KeyEvent.VK_UP && array[1] == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            velx = 4;
            vely = 4;
        } else if (array[0] == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT && array[1] == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            velx = 4;
            vely = -4;
        } else if (array[0] == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && array[1] == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            velx = -4;
            vely = 4;
        }
    } else {
        if (c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            velx = -4;
            vely = 0;
        } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            velx = 4;
            vely = 0;
        } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            velx = 0;
            vely = -4;
        } else if (c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            velx = 0;
            vely = 4;
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    velx = 0;
    vely = 0;

    pressed.remove(Integer.valueOf(arg0.getKeyCode()));
}
```

Comment: add these line in `keyPressed()` method not in `actionPerformed()`

Comment: i see ...and do i have to put all my other conditions in the else block you have left incomplete?

Comment: Yes you have to put them also. Should I post complete code. I just mentioned the changes.

Comment: any way to move in both diagonals

Comment: @OOPer, A user doesn't know what Alt+LEFT means. It could go up/left or down/left. Normally you would just combine the UP and LEFT keys to go diagonally up and left.

Comment: Finally I have updated my code as per you requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings`.

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and a complete solution that uses `Key Bindings`.