# Can I use a loop in order to go horizontally and vertically at the same time?

Tags: java, loops, keyboard, focus, paint

I'm making this simple game(just for fun) and when I say simple, I really want it to be simple. Now so far I have a square that I can move anywhere I want. I'm using KeyListeners(works completely fine, I don't want to use KeyBindings for this current project) and I was wondering if I can just use loops in order to make it go both horizontally and vertically at the same time. 
In this code you can witness my ***attempt*** of putting in the loop and it's giving me an error under the while saying:

> Syntax error on token while

I have two questions
1. Will the loop even get what I want done? 
   if no, what do you suggest?
2. If yes, what's wrong with my while loop?

Thank you

**My Code:**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y = 0, velx =0, vely =0, loop = 0;

    public MyGame() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x,y,50,30);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(x < 0)
        {
            velx=0;
            x = 0;  
        }

        if(x > 530)
        {
            velx=0;
            x = 530;    
        }

        if(y < 0)
        {
            vely=0;
            y = 0;  
        }

        if(y > 330)
        {
            vely=0;
            y = 330;    
        }

        x += velx;
        y += vely;
        repaint();
    }
    while (loop = 0) {
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            vely = 1;
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            vely = -1;
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            vely = 0;
            velx = -1;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            vely = 0;
            velx = 1;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        velx=0;
        vely=0;
    }}


    public static void main (String arge[]){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        MyGame s = new MyGame();
        f.add(s);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: `loop = 0`. Look closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you cannot declare a loop outside of a method.
To fix your problem you should remove the loop and instead change your vely/velx assignments.
To register mutiple keys at the same time you should only set one variable to either 1 or -1 and just leave the other one be.

```
if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
   vely = 1;
}
```

now since you are registering multiple keys you also have to differentiate between them in the keyreleased method where you should now set the appropriate velocity to 0 and let the other one stay as it is.

Comment: Wait what? I don't understand how that works but it works. That's so weird. Thank you

Comment: keypressed is called everytime a key is pressed. removing the velx=0 will ensure that you dont overwrite the actions of another key (as long as it doesnt change the same global variable).

Comment: Oh wow I never knew that. I always thought both x and y needed to be there even if they didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `while (loop = 0) {` that is not declared inside a method or constructor.

---

I have already posted the complete code in the exactly same context to go horizontally and vertically at the same time.

Please have a look at below posts

- [Diagonal movement of a sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580933/diagonal-movement-of-a-sprite/22581039#22581039)
- [KeyListener not changing the JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22697284/keylistener-not-changing-the-jpanel/22697568#22697568)

[image]

Comment: Thank you but crimeson already taught me a very simple way out. If I could I would vote your answer but I can't. Thanks for helping out.